# Extraer/Filtrar info de un data.frame en R

Tags: r, filtro

el asunto es este, espero me puedan ayudar:

Tengo dos archivos (tablas) importados en R, el primero es una tabla pequeña con nombres de referencia, el segundo son nombres repetidos con datos estadísticos, necesito hacer un filtro donde queden SOLO los nombres que coincidan con el primer archivo, junto con los demás datos estadísticos, es decir reducir el segundo archivo con los criterios del primer archivo, ya que me sobran nombres, necesito hacer una especie de match y que me quede toda la información de estos a forma de tabla . Alguna idea?

Comment: Bienevenido Pedro R. Orozco a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: También trata de crear un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder testear la solución creamos unos datos aleatorios con las estructura de tus datos. Un data.frame con claves a conservar, al que llamamos `df1` y un data.frame con esas mismas claves y otras claves diferentes, además de unos datos aleatorios que simulan los estadísticos.

```
set.seed(2018)
df1 <- data.frame(claves = letters[1:3],    # a, b y c
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(claves = sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), #100 letras al azar, algunas son a, b o c 
                  estadisticos = rnorm(100),                     #Unos datos numéricos al azar que simulan los estadísticos
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Para filtrar vamos a pedir a R que conserve solo las filas de `df2` en las que el valor de la columna clave también está presente en las claves de `df1`. Usamos el operador `%in` (pertenencia). Si usáramos `==` (igualdad) solo verificaría igualdad con un elemento, y nosotros que queremos verificar igualdad en varios elementos. 
Usamos `df2[ , ]` para especificar que queremos un subconjunto de ese objeto. El nombre `claves` es irrelevante, las columnas se podrían llamar de cualquier manera.

```
df2[df2$claves %in% df1$claves, ]
```

Es una operación básica y hay muchas formas de hacerlo. Esta solución usa operadores más simples posibles. Si tus datos son **muy** grandes podría ser algo lenta. En ese caso podría ser más rápido trabajar con un join de `dplyr`, que suelen ser más rápidos:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2)
```

`left_join` indica que se conservarán solo los valores del data.frame del lado izquierdo (en este caso `df1`) que coinciden con los del lado derecho (`df2`).

> En este caso sí es necesario que los nombres de columna de empate (clave) sean exactamente iguales en ambos data.frame, de lo contrario `left_join` no sabría por qué columna unir. Se pueden especificar los nombres con el argumento `by=`, pero es más complicado.

Comment: Me sirvió totalmente muchas gracias !!